# With constant travel, is it possible to not have a tax residence?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, european-union, tax-residency

We're in the EU (EU passports) and planning on spending the next couple years traveling. Income is coming through a company I have set in a country I was never a resident of.

The only taxes I'm normally liable for is my personal income, at my place of residence.

During the travel period, we will not stay longer than 2-3 month in a specific country, therefore we don't establish tax residence in any of them.

In that situation, can I avoid paying income tax during that time?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_traveler

Comment: I think in general, most jurisdictions consider that once you have established residency, residency is maintained by *not* establishing a residency elsewhere, not by continued presence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

All [tax treaties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_treaty) (which
allow personal/investment income paid in one country to get shifted to another country)
require you to claim (at least in your mind; paperwork might not be needed)
an official country of residence for each piece of income.  So,
you will then need to file taxes for at least one claimed country.  If you
claim multiple countries, you probably can use foreign tax credits to prevent
double-taxation, but your total taxes are probably minimized claiming just one
country for all income.

Comment: so, if I understand properly, I need to elect where my tax residence is. But if I don't spend a minimum of time in a place, I can't establish a residence there since I wouldn't be able to get a tax id in that location. How can that work then?

Comment: As @chepner commented, you probably should just stick with the country you last filed taxes with.  If you really can't get a different tax ID, it seems you have no other option.

Comment: If you don't establish a new tax residence, your existing tax residence remains in place. This is true on both the international level and on a state-by-state level within the US. People who plan to travel indefinitely sometimes work very hard to establish residency in a low-tax jurisdiction.